# Searching data within a node which can be anywhere

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have a tag `<H>some data</H>`. This tag can come anywhere within the XML file. Below is an example-

```
<Name>This is some data. It is an <H>highlighted text</H></Name>
  <DDesc>Here is the Detailed <H>Description</H>
     <Features>Following are the important <H>features of</H> the product</Features>
         <Construction>Some text <H>goes here</H></Construction>
         <Design>Some design <H>stuff</H> information</Design>
     </Features>
  </DDesc>
</Name>
```

Now I want to get the contents of `<H>..</H>` tags. This tag is being used in all tags.
How to get it?

Comment: Do you want a single string as the result or a collection of strings, one for each h element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
//H/text()
```

this selects any text node that is a child of any `H` element in the XML document.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a general syntax for that:**

```
//ElementName
```

This is going to return all descendant elements of root element named as `ElementName`. Note that giving `/` means `child::` where as `//` means `descendant::`.

If you like to return descendant elements within root then use something like:

```
//*
```